# What is the strategy for reaching the restaurant at the edge of the universe?

Tags: dolphin-olympics-2

I just can't seem to reach the restaurant at the edge of the universe in [Dolphin Olympics 2](http://www.kongregate.com/games/arawkins/dolphin-olympics-2). I've read a bunch of forum posts people have made, and I checked out [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1HX8h9AoIG0) (which was a little choppy), but there's still something I'm missing. I think it's the tailslides/starslides that are the key component that I can't seem to get right.

What strategy should I be following, and (if they are necessary) how should I be performing the tailslides and starslides correctly?

Comment: The answer is, of course, 42.

Comment: @squillman: How, oh how, did I not see that coming? =P

Comment: Hey, it's late.  :)

Comment: @squillman: Yes, it's definitely time for bed. Thanks for the fish. ;)

Comment: how many of the fish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point is to leave and re-enter the water at very shallow angles, it increases your speed at the highest possible acceleration, repeat the basic jumps until you have enough speed to fly straight out of the water, there's no real strategy beyond getting as much speed as you can and then launching yourself up. Keep at it, perseverance is your greatest tool!